# Retrieve nested array in laravel view

Tags: arrays, laravel, object

My object seems like

```
 { ["message"]=> object(Google_Service_Gmail_Message)#154 (14)
     {  ["historyId"]=> string(4) "1001" 
        ["id"]=> string(16) "15096ab785de59868a" 
        ["internalDate"]=> string(13) "1445635228000" 
        ["labelIds"]=> array(4) 
             { [0]=> string(5) "INBOX" 
               [1]=> string(9) "IMPORTANT" 
               [2]=> string(17) "CATEGORY_PERSONAL" 
               [3]=> string(6) "UNREAD" }....
```

My problem is, for `history id` i can get it by `$message->historyId`.

but how can i render `labelIds` content in the view page. I like to have particularly `UNREAD`. How can i?

Comment: type $message->labelIds then you will get an array,then foreach the array and you will get output.

Comment: `$message->labelIds[3]` ?

Answer (score 0):

The answers in the comments are correct.  Since you specifically noted Laravel here, I will add the Laravel-specific helper functions that may be what you are after.

For Laravel objects, "array_get" will return down to any nested level you like using dot notation.  You can then also perform any other functions you need on it.  In your example this might work out to be:

```
array_get($message, 'labelsIds', 'default');
```

The above can be reset according to the level you want to get and includes a default which you could set to UNREAD if you like.

Also, if you want to return a flattened array containing all of the nested values (the keys would be dropped), you can use Laravel 4.2's array_fetch.

Take a look at the manuals on this - it might be helpful:  http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-get   and http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers for fetch